# Can't acces array of pointers from another function

Tags: c++, arrays

Im wiriting this matrix program that will create matrix(2d array) and store value in them. Currenty i have a problem with getting to a specific element -mtx[rows][cols]=value is giving me "expression must be pointer to object type" error with rows and cols underlined

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<cstdlib>
    #include"matrix.h"

    Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int cols)
    {
        int **mtx=new int*[rows];
        for(int i=0; i<rows; i++)
        {
            mtx[i]=new int[cols];
        }   
    }
    void Matrix::setElem(int rows, int cols, int value)
    {
       mtx[rows][cols] = value;

    }



//.h file

#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H
#include<cstdint>

class Matrix
{

    int rows;
    int cols;
    int mtx;
    public:



    Matrix(int rows, int cols);

   void setElem(int rows, int cols, int value);
};
#endif
```

Comment: `int **mtx` creates a variable that is local to the constructor. Do you have a member by the name of `mtx` or did you mean to make `mtx` a member?

Comment: is `mtx` supposed to be a class variable? Its definition is scoped to the constructor and not the class. Therefore it has no visibility inside `setElem`

Comment: mtx is a class member

Comment: it's generally a good idea to avoid variable shadowing between class member variables and parameters of it's member functions. instead you could write _rows, _cols and _mtx as your class members and rows, cols as parameter names. just for keeping everything in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining you matrix in the class like this

```
int mtx;
```

then you redefine it in the constructor like this

```
int **mtx;
```

When you re-define a class variable in function it you override the class variable for the scope of that function after the variable declaration. Change the declaration in the class to

```
int **mtx;
```

and remove it from the constructor and it should work fine. (You also need a destructor)

This should work

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include"matrix.h"

Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int cols)
{
    //int **mtx=new int*[rows]; // removed
    mtx=new int*[rows]; // just allocate
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++)
    {
        mtx[i]=new int[cols];
    }
    this->rows = rows;
    this->cols = cols;

}
void Matrix::setElem(int rows, int cols, int value)
{
   mtx[rows][cols] = value;
}

//.h file
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H
#include<cstdint>

class Matrix
{

    int rows;
    int cols;
    int **mtx; // added stars
    public:

    Matrix(int rows, int cols);
    //~Matrix(void); // You also need a destructor. 

    void setElem(int rows, int cols, int value);
};
#endif
```

Comment: thanks, but now im getting segmentation fault every time i use the setElem function

Comment: It should work now. I removed declaration but keep allocation. You still need to fix the destructor or it will leak memory.